# How to upload random image after a message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello i want to make my bot upload random image after message. example: below code when a member types `!ping` bot reply's `Pong` followed by uploading a image `1.png`. but i need to make bot upload a random image from a folder.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    fp = random.choice(os.listdir("randomimagefoldername"))
    await bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "randomimagefoldername/{}".format(fp), content="Pong")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
import os
import random
...
fp = random.choice(os.listdir("randomimagefoldername"))
await bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "randomimagefoldername/{}".format(fp))
```

Comment: You may need to add a new line for the 'Pong' message. Try adding 
    `await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, content="Pong")`

Comment: @Bosen `content="Pong"` should work.  Could you pose the `send_file` line you tried, and describe a little more clearly how it didn't work?

Comment: @Bosen You can't have a keyword argument in front of a positional argument (re-read the error message).  It's an easy fix: `await bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel,"randomimagefoldername/{}".format(fp),  content="Pong")`

Comment: @Bosen You'll have to use [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).  How exactly do you want the formatted string to look?

Comment: @Bosen `say` just does `str(diff)` under the hood.  `content=str(diff)` should be sufficent

Comment: What exactly do you want the text of the message to be?  Assuming you have `diff =100`, say

Comment: @Bosen Are you just looking for something like `content="Pong {}".format(diff)`?